# XSLT: Test Parameter to know if it has been set

Tags: xslt

I have a situation where the param won't be set, but my attempts to capture & handle the sitation aren't working.

I'm using the following:

```
<xsl:template match="xs:complexType">
  <xsl:param name="prefix" />

  <xsl:variable name="prefix-no-core">
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- if no value, default to 'AcRec' -->
      <xsl:when test="not($prefix)"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="'AcRec'" />
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- if 'core', leave as empty string -->
      <xsl:when test="$prefix = 'core'">
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- if 'AcRec', set the value -->
      <xsl:when test="$prefix = 'AcRec'">
        <xsl:value-of select="$prefix" />
      </xsl:when>               
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xs:complexType name="{concat($prefix-no-core, @name)}">
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

I've also tried $prefix='' in the first test - neither work.  but if I use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="not($prefix)" />
```

... the value prints out as true.  But using that in my xsl:choose doesn't produce any output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of the suggestions made to date, the only solution that worked was to always set the parameter value when a call to the template is made.  For example, previously I had:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//xs:complexType[@name='AddressType']" />
```

This had to be changed to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//xs:complexType[@name='AddressType']">
  <xsl:with-param name="prefix" select="'AcRec'" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

I'd really like to know why not($param) and $param='' don't work in a WHEN test, yet I can get the value of not($param) in a xsl:value-of statement.

Answer (score 9):

You can specify a default value for the parameter, that way when it isn't passed, you can check for it.

Though in your example, it looks like just having a default value would simplify things greatly.

```
<xsl:template match="xs:complexType">
  <xsl:param name="prefix" select="'default-value'" /> <!-- SET default -->

  <xsl:variable name="prefix-no-core">
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- if no value, default to 'AcRec' -->
      <xsl:when test="$prefix = 'default-value'"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="'AcRec'" />
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- if 'core', leave as empty string -->
      <xsl:when test="$prefix = 'core'">
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- if 'AcRec', set the value -->
      <xsl:when test="$prefix = 'AcRec'">
        <xsl:value-of select="$prefix" />
      </xsl:when>                       
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xs:complexType name="{concat($prefix-no-core, @name)}">
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

Call like this, and the value will be 'default-value':

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//xs:complexType[@name='AddressType']" />
```

Call like this, and the value will be 'passed-value':

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="//xs:complexType[@name='AddressType']">
    <xsl:with-param name="prefix" value="'passed-value'"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

EDIT: For completeness, the simplified form of the original example is:

```
<xsl:template match="xs:complexType">
  <xsl:param name="prefix" select="'AcRec'"/>

  <xsl:variable name="prefix-no-core">
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- if 'core', leave as empty string -->
      <xsl:when test="$prefix = 'core'">
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- defaults to 'AcRec' -->
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="$prefix" />
      </xsl:otherwise>                       
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xs:complexType name="{concat($prefix-no-core, @name)}">
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If you need a default value of a parameter that doesn't come from any XML element (i.e. a hardcoded literal value), use `<xsl:param name="prefix">literal value here</xsl:param>`

Answer (score 1):

Note: replaced old answer, check history if you want it.

The following input:

```
<test xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:complexType name="something"/>
    <xs:complexType name="somethingElse"/>
</test>
```

Fed to the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="node()">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="xs:complexType">
        <xsl:param name="prefix" />
        <xsl:variable name="prefix-no-core">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not($prefix)">AcRec</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$prefix = 'core'"/>
                <xsl:when test="$prefix = 'AcRec'">AcRec</xsl:when>                       
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xs:complexType name="{concat($prefix-no-core, @name)}"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Gives the following result:

```
<xs:complexType name="AcRecsomething" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
<xs:complexType name="AcRecsomethingElse" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
```

I'm not sure what more you're looking for...

Comment: I need to support the possibility of other prefixes.

Comment: Tried it - the xsl:otherwise is giving me false positives, applying the prefix to those it should not.

Comment: When do you not want to apply the prefix?  Again, give us the complete use-case.  If prefix=core, you want no prefix.  If prefix is not set, you want AcDec as the prefix.  What is the other case?  Do you want to use the prefix provided, or do you want to have to manually add a case for each "allowed" prefix.  If so, what happens the caller provides a prefix you don't recognize?

Comment: Does the first code snippet work?  If not, what is the problem you are seeing with it?

Comment: For the current file, "core" and "AcRec" are the only prefixes I can expect.  However, I will not use != 'core' because the source could change.  The issue is that the first time the template runs, there won't be a prefix value.  But attempts to catch that situation in a WHEN test have all failed - not($prefix) and $prefix='' do not execute when I test it.

Comment: Try your example where you provide 'core' as the prefix - it won't work.  Output ultimately is arbitrary - the point is to accurately handle when a parameter/variable value is/is not set.

Answer (score 1):

It's a hack, but I have had success by first wrapping the parameter with the normalize-space() function before testing for an empty param.

```
<xsl:value-of select="not(normalize-space($prefix))" />
```

Comment: I tried that as a when clause - it was handling false positives.